# Is there a better way to determine what media queries uses for its width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need this value to use in JavaScript.  I find it using this snippet of code I designed/developed, which detects it via events and a precision of 10px and releases it to a global variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/jbnt7nh1/16/

```
var mq,i;
if (window.matchMedia) {
     // ... snip
}
```

I was curious if this value - `$A.inner_width` always mimics `window.innerWidth`

Comment: Aren't you just looking for window.innerWidth?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I'm sure it doesn't mimic media queries, but a media query is simply that: a CSS query that is restricted based on certain criteria.  If we understood what you were trying to do, it might allow us to answer a bit better.

Comment: You've used `if (matchMedia)` in one place then, if that's truthy, used `window.matchMedia` to call it. That's exactly backward. You want `if (window.matchMedia)`, and then once you know it's there, either `window.matchMedia` or just `matchMedia` to call it. The way you have it, on browsers that don't have the function, it'll throw a `ReferenceError` because you're trying to read the value of an undefined symbol in the `if`.

Comment: @cadegalt: Media queries are a big deal **in CSS**, because they're extremely responsive, declarative, and keep the styling separated from the code. Media queries in JavaScript aren't that big a deal, but if you sometimes have the need for the JavaScript to perfectly match the CSS decision, `matchMedia` does that job. Also, you don't have to translate, you can use the same expressions with both.

Comment: @T.J. - but if I modify a CSS property in JavaScript and it determines it's value from a media query, once the page changes dimensions, the media query will not work.  This causes some extremely hard to read code.  If you are dynamically changing CSS in JS, it's better to just do the media queries in JS as well.

Comment: ...and still by using JS to simply swap out classes, all the presentation layer is still in the CSS/HTML.